# JPA Criteria api - Total records for concrete query within pagination

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.0, criteria-api, jpa-2.1

I am programming function for pagination in my repository layer. Function receive as parameters spring's pageable object and some value like this:

```
public Page<Foo> filterFoo(Pageable pageable, String value) {
   CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
   CriteriaQuery<Foo> fooQuery = cb.createQuery(Foo.class);
   Root<Foo> foo = fooQuery .from(Foo.class);
   fooQuery .where(adding predicate for match value);

   List<Foo> result = entityManager.createQuery(fooQuery )
      .setFirstResult((pageable.getPageNumber() - 1) * pageable.getPageSize())
      .setMaxResults(pageable.getPageSize())
      .getResultList();
   return new PageImpl<>(result, pageable, xxxx);
}
```

Function return spring's PageImpl object filled with my result. To PageImpl I also need set total count of objects which suit predicates. This count number have to be of course without maxResult and firstResult. Is possible create another database call with my fooQuery to get total database records for that query without limit? What is the best practise to use pageable and criteria api in JPA? Thank you in advice.

Comment: Hi, Did you manage to find a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

Because generated SQL uses aliases - you may need make separate query for get total count of rows.
For example:

```
CriteriaQuery<Long> countQuery = cb.createQuery(Long.class);
countQuery.select(cb.count(countQuery.from(Foo.class)));
if (Objects.nonNull(filters)) {
    countQuery.where(filters);
}
return new PageImpl<>(result, pageable, em.createQuery(countQuery).getSingleResult());
```

where `filters` is equal to your `adding predicate for match value` expression.

Also, you may use a TupleQuery with custom SQL function for calculate count of rows in one `select` query.
Like this:

```
public class SqlFunctionsMetadataBuilderContributor implements MetadataBuilderContributor {
    @Override
    public void contribute(MetadataBuilder metadataBuilder) {
        metadataBuilder.applySqlFunction(
            "count_over",
            new SQLFunctionTemplate(
                StandardBasicTypes.LONG,
                "(count(?1) over())"
            )
        );
    }
}
```

and Criteria:

```
public Page<Foo> findAll(Specification<Foo> specification, Pageable pageable) {
    CriteriaQuery<Tuple> cq = cb.createTupleQuery();
    Root<Foo.class> fooRoot = cq.from(Foo.class);
    cq.select(cb.tuple(fooRoot, cb.function("count_over", Long.class, fooRoot.get("id"))));

    Predicate filters = specification.toPredicate(fooRoot, cq, cb);
    if (Objects.nonNull(filters)) {
        cq.where(filters);
    }

    TypedQuery<Tuple> query = em.createQuery(cq);
    query.setFirstResult((int) pageable.getOffset());
    query.setMaxResults(pageable.getPageSize());
    List<Tuple> result = query.getResultList();
    if (result.isEmpty()) {
        return new PageImpl<>(List.of());
    }
    return new PageImpl<>(
        result.stream().map(tuple -> (Foo) tuple.get(0)).collect(toUnmodifiableList()),
        pageable,
        (long) result.get(0).get(1)
    );
}
```

See more about `SQLFunction`: https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-sql-function-jpql-criteria-api-query/ and [Custom SQL for Order in JPA Criteria API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52705756/custom-sql-for-order-in-jpa-criteria-api)